# Animate rectangle shape the distance of a mouseClick

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2

I've been stuck with this silly bug for the last few hours now. Basically, I want to animate (slide) the little rectangle up to where I click the mouse in the box (the X value is all I care about right now). The source below does exactly that.

However, what I really want is to save the end point's location so that if I were to click the midpoint of the pane, the box slides up to the halfway point (just as said above), then if I were to click 3/4 of the way, the box would slide **from the halfway point to the 3/4 mark.**

It seems like all we would have to do would be to setX(), right? Well uncomment where I save the rectangle's X coordinates and run it again. You'll see that **it jumps!** Why? I have absolutely no clue and have been stuck trying to find a fix/workaround for this pesky bug for the last few hours now and have gotten nowhere. If anybody could point me in the right direction I will pay it forward, I promise.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TimelineEvents extends Application {

    Rectangle myRectangle;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane mainPane = new Pane(); // Create a ball pane
        //ballPane.play();
        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        myRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 20, 30, 30);

        mainPane.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> {
            animate(event);
        });

        mainPane.getChildren().add(myRectangle);
    }

    public void animate(MouseEvent event) {

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        System.out.println(myRectangle.getY());
        timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
                        new KeyValue(myRectangle.translateXProperty(), 0),
                        new KeyValue(myRectangle.translateYProperty(), 0)
                ),
                new KeyFrame(new Duration(1000),
                        new KeyValue(myRectangle.translateXProperty(), event.getX()),
                        new KeyValue(myRectangle.translateYProperty(), 0)
                )
        );

        timeline.play();

        timeline.setOnFinished((ActionEvent) -> {
            //myRectangle.setX(event.getX());
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have started the animation always at the zero position, change the animation like this:

```
timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
      new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
         new KeyValue(myRectangle.translateXProperty(), myRectangle.getTranslateX()),
          new KeyValue(myRectangle.translateYProperty(), 0)
      ),
....
```

**EDIT:**
Incorporating the comment, all you need is

```
timeline.getKeyFrames().add(
        new KeyFrame(new Duration(1000),
                new KeyValue(myRectangle.translateXProperty(), event.getX())
        )
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you fast and correct answer. I'm a new user to the SO forums so I can't vote on your answer, but I will once I reach 15 points

Comment: @JPC although this answer works, the whole KeyFrame at duration 0 is redundant---it does not do anything, just keeps the rectangle in place. You can safely remove this KeyFrame. Also, in the second KeyFrame, you don't need to animate the `translateYProperty()`, since it does not change.